# How to split products based on what the category tab has in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a page that has tabs and each tab is a category of a product. What I'm trying to do is split
the products based the category, but I'm struggling on how to go about it. What I get is a list of all the products instead of only the
products that is attached to that category

Here is my controller

```
    public function getProductCategories(User $user)
    {
        $products = Product::find($user->user_id);
        $productCategories = $products->categories();
        $categories = $productCategories->distinct()->pluck('category');

        $allCategories = Category::where('product_id', $categories->id)->groupBy('id', 'category')->get();

        return [
            'categories' => $categories,
            'allCategories' => $allCategories
        ];
    }
```

My vue

```
    <template>
        <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation" v-for="category in categories">
                <a class="nav-link active"
                    id="home-tab"
                    data-toggle="tab"
                    :href="'#'+category"
                    role="tab"
                    aria-controls="home"
                    aria-selected="true"
                >
                    {{ category }}
                </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" v-for="category in allCategories" :id="category.name">
                    {{ category.name }}
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            props: ['user'],
            data() {
                return {
                categories: null,
                allCategories: null
                }
            },
            methods: {
            getProductCategories(){
                axios.get('/api/admin/products/'+this.user.id+'/categories').then(response => {
                this.categories = response.data.categories;
                this.allCategories = response.data.allCategories;
                })
            }
            },
            mounted(){
                this.getProductCategories();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 2 possible solutions

1. It could be that your `v-for` should be iterating through a different object.
   **Computed Properties**, you could have computed properties that take in arguments and return a filtered array of products from the array of all products. i.e.

   ```js
   // in Template 
   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" v-for="category in allCategories" :id="category.name">
          {{ singleCategoryProducts(category.name) }}
   </div>

   // in script 
   props: [/* whateverProps*/],
   data: {/* whatever Data */},
   computed: {
     singleCategoryProducts(categoryName){
       // Filter all products and return an array of products of the specific category
       return this.allProducts.filter(product => product.category === categoryName )
     }
   }
   // Note that you can also have a method to return the same - putting this here for example
   methods: {
     singleCategoryProducts(categoryName){
       // Filter all products and return an array of products of the specific category
       return this.allProducts.filter(product => product.category === categoryName )
     }
   }
   ```
2. I don't know the shape of your data, so, that's a bit of a challenge. But I would imagine that you have all the users products, and the complete list of categories. If you could provide something like a JSON object (or a couple of JSON objects) to show what your data is like, then that would provide some much-needed context.

Also, I highly recommend using vuex for state management if you're not using it already. Situations like this is where Vuex really shines. Just a suggestion.